# Calculate percentage through multiple sheets in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many sheets that look similar to this :

| Q1 | N |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 |
| 2 | 78 |
| 3 | 101 |
| 4 | 132 |

The number of lines can differ from one sheet to the other but they always have two columns.

What I am trying to do is to calculate a sum for the B column and use that to then calculate the share of each answer in column C as such:

| Q1 | N | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | 10 % |
| 2 | 78 | 22 % |
| 3 | 101 | 29 % |
| 4 | 132 | 38 % |
|  | 437 | 100 % |

I have managed to calculate the sum across all sheets (see code below) but I have trouble understanding how to calculate the percentage. Any clues would be appreciated!

```
Sub Clean_up()
'
' Clean_up Macro
'

'
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If sht.Visible Then
    sht.Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
 
    [C1].Value = "%"

    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell = "NA"

    Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B:B"))

End If

Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Learn to use variables. You can store the sum and each number then divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Clean_Up()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim total As Double
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then
            
            ws.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "0"
            ws.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For r = 2 To lastRow
                total = total + ws.Cells(r, 2).Value
            Next r
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = total
            ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = 1
            
            ' Place percentages
            For r = 2 To lastRow
                ws.Cells(r, 3).Value = ws.Cells(r, 2).Value / total
            Next r
            
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Manny! I get a type mismatch error for this line however : "total = total + ws.Cells(r, 2).Value". Would you know why?

Comment: Do you have any Non-numbers in the second column?

Comment: That was my first guess, I have a colomn header but that's it.

Comment: you could probably force it to work by doing:

total = total + CDbl(ws.Cells(r, 2).Value)

Personally, I would attempt to figure out which value is causing the problem by doing 
Debug.Print  ws.Cells(r, 2).Value right before the error line

Comment: Thanks Manny! I managed to make it work. Cheers

Comment: no worries, if you think the solution I provided answered your question don't forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Quick examples of taking generating a percentage:

```
'Inserting a formula to the cell:
With sheets(1)
    .range(.cells(1,3),.cells(4,3)).formula = "=B1/Sum(B$1:B$4)"
End with

'Outputting a value to the cell
With sheets(1)
    dim sumOfValues as double:  sumofValues = Application.Sum(.range(.cells(1,3),.cells(4,3)))
    dim iterator as long
    for iterator = 1 to 4
        .cells(iterator,3).value = .cells(iterator,2).value/sumOfValues
    next iterator
End with
```

You would dynamically want to find your ranges first/last row, though the above would get you the percentage part.